# MS MFA Slave is not Authenticating

Tags: azure, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I've setup a HA MS MFA environment which will be mainly used for RDP Gateways.

I've 2 MSMFA Servers and 2 RDPGWs on two VM-Hosts, so there should always be one Host be able to reboot.

I get authenticated, as long as the NPS Server on the RDPGW authenticates through the master of the MSMFAs.

I already changed the master role on the MSMFAs. It didn't work then until I changed the primary RADIUS server on the NPSs.

I cannot imagine why the slave (does not matter what one of the both MSMFAs is in the slave role) does not authenticate.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: In my opinion, this question relates to the infrastructure and is not suited for SO. Here you can see the rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A stateless load balanced or stateful load balancing you are use?

Comment: Hi the RDPGWS are in a statefull loadbalancing.
But my Problem is, as soon as the RADIUS on MSMFA1 is marked unavailable by the RDPGW, the RDPGW tries to use the MSMFA2 but that one does not answer the request. a call is made, but no answer is made to the RDPGW.